# String sorting null values

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have a string arraylist with some `null` values and some strings. I don't want to sort the arraylist but I should sort the arraylist such that null values comes last.  Lets say arraylist is `{1,2,null,6,5,null, 3}`, I should get null values last  `{1,2,6,5,3,null,null}`.

Solution , I currently have:
Right now, I am constructing new arraylist and If the value is `null`, I am not pushing it to new list otherwise I am adding it to new arraylist.

Any other better solution?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: post the code of what you tried so far

Comment: Build your own *comparator* and pass that to the sorter.

Comment: Your approach seems fine, since you don't want to actually sort the List. You just iterate over the List once. You could modify the original List if you prefer that over creating a new list (whenever you encounter a null value, remove it).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Custom Comparator to pass to sort:

```
public class StringComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        if (s1 != null && s2 != null)
            return s1.compareTo(s2);
        return (s1 == null) ? 1 : -1;
    }
}
```

then:

```
Collectios.sort(list, new StringComparator());
```

Answer (score 16):

If you are using Java 8, you can easily build the comparator you need:

```
Arrays.sort(stringArray, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder()));
```

But if you not using java 8 you can have a comparator like below

```
public class StringNullComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    public int compare(String stringOne, String stringTwo) {
        if (stringOne != null && stringTwo != null)
            return stringOne.compareTo(stringTwo);
        return (stringOne == stringTwo)?0:(stringOne==null? 1 : -1);
    }
}
```

And you can use at stated below

```
Arrays.sort(stringArray, new StringNullComparator());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid explicitly iterating over the whole list you could use ArrayList.indexOf() to find the null values, then remove() them. If you want to keep the values in the list you can then just add a null value to the end of the list. However I would imagine this approach is not great in terms of performance if this is a concern.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [NullComparator from apache](http://www.massapi.com/class/nu/NullComparator.html).

```
Collections.sort(list, new NullComparator());
```

Answer (score 0):

what about constructing new arraylist and If it  a real value add it to the new list and if it is a null increment a counter.At last add the number of null equal to counter value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort null to the end and keep the order for the non-null elements this `Comparator` would do that :

```
class CompareStrings implements Comparator<String> {

    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        if (o1 == null && o2 != null)
            return 1;
        if (o2 == null && o1 != null)
            return -1;
        return 0;
    }   
}
```

If both `String` are null or non-null they will compare equal. If only one is null it will compare as smaller than the non-null one.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
class MyInteger implements Comparator<Integer> {
    public int compare(Integer arg0, Integer arg1) {
        if(arg1 == null) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And we can use it like:

```
List<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
al.add(1);
al.add(2);
al.add(null);
al.add(6);
al.add(5);
al.add(null);
al.add(3);

Collections.sort(al, new MyInteger());
```

Answer (score 0):

All other solutions involve sorting. As you mentioned, you don't really need sorting. In case time complexity is a concern, you can use the following linear time solution (in-place):

```
  public static <T> void nullsToEndInPlace(List<T> l) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = l.size() - 1;
    while (i < j) {
      T left = l.get(i);
      T right = l.get(j);
      if (left != null) {
        i++;
      } else if (right == null) {
        j--;
      } else {
        l.set(i, right);
        l.set(j, null);
        i++;
        j--;
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("BR64");
    list.add("SWG620");
    list.add("");
    list.add("sw0");
    list.add("R124");
    list.add("R219");
    list.add("TaGh20");
    list.add("SW6505");
    list.add("");
    list.add(null);
    list.add("SW_6505");
    list.add("swd_157");
    list.add("localhost");
    list.add("qaGh20_241");
    list.add("gen");
    list.add(null);
    list.add("taGh20");
    list.add("zen");
    list.add("QWG");
    list.add("SWG62_");
    list.add("SWG620");

    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            if (o1 != null && o2 != null && o1.length() > 0 && o2.length() > 0) {
                return (Character.toLowerCase(o1.charAt(0)) == Character.toLowerCase(o2.charAt(0)))
                        ? o1.compareTo(o2)
                        : (Character.toLowerCase(o1.charAt(0)) + o1.substring(1))
                                .compareTo((Character.toLowerCase(o2.charAt(0)) + o2.substring(1)));
            } else {
                return (o1 == o2) ? 0 : ((o1 == null || o1 == "") ? 1 : -1);
            }
        }
    });
    System.out.println(list);
```

Output-:[BR64, gen, localhost, QWG, qaGh20_241, R124, R219, SW6505, SWG620, SWG620, SWG62_, SW_6505, sw0, swd_157, TaGh20, taGh20, zen, , , null, null]

Answer (score 0):

Both `list.sort()` and `sorted()` have a key parameter to specify a function to be called on each list element prior to making comparisons.

For example, here’s a case-insensitive string comparison:

```
sorted("This is a test string from sohan".split(), key=str.lower)                                                                                                                   
['a', 'from', 'is', 'sohan', 'string', 'test', 'This']
```

here, **`key=str.lower()`** will convert every string to lower case and then sort the result.

[For more info about **sorting** click here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html)